# how to make a regular grid base on some irregular points in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, grid

I have a numpy array of `x` and `y` coordinates and want to make it regular. The array is sorted based on its `x` values (first column):

```
import numpy as np
Irregular_points = np.array([[1.1,5.], [0.85,7.1], [0.9,9], [1.1,11], [1.,13.1],
                   [1.9,5.2], [2.,6.9], [1.95,9], [2.1,11.1], [2.,13.1],
                   [3.0,5.1], [3.1,7.0], [3.,9], [3.0,11.], [3.1,12.8]])
```

I want to firtly find out which points have almost the same `x` values: it will be the first five rows, middle five rows and last five rows. One signal for finding these points is that `y` value decreases when I go to the next group. Then, I want to replace the `x` values of each group with the average value. For example in the fisrt five rows `x` values are `1.1`, `0.85`, `0.9`, `1.1` and `1.` and the average is `0.98`. I want to do the same for next two parts.

For `y` values I again want to find similar ones which fall into five groups and then replace them with average of each group. `y` values of the first group are `5.`, `5.2` and `5.1` and average is `5.1`. Finally, my points should be like the following array:

```
Regular_points = np.array([[0.98,5.1], [0.98,7.0], [0.98,9.0], [0.98,11.03], [0.98,13.0],
                   [1.98,5.1], [1.98,7.0], [1.98,9.0], [1.98,11.03], [1.98,13.0],
                   [3.04,5.1], [3.04,7.0], [3.04,9.0], [3.04,11.03], [3.04,13.0]])
```

I tried to `round` numbers but it did not work for real cases and I need to make these averages. I very much appreciate any help. The figure clearly shows what I want. Red dots are irregular points but by replacing averages, blue dots can be resulted.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to use a shape = (3, 5, 2) for both `irregular_points` and `regular_points` unless you're forced to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're averaging rows and columns, you'll need to use a different shape. Then separate `x` and `y` coords, average them by different axis and use [`np.transpose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.transpose.html) + [`np.meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) for nice display:

```
irregular_points = np.array([[1.1,5.], [0.85,7.1], [0.9,9], [1.1,11], [1.,13.1],
                             [1.9,5.2], [2.,6.9], [1.95,9], [2.1,11.1], [2.,13.1],
                             [3.0,5.1], [3.1,7.0], [3.,9], [3.0,11.], [3.1,12.8]])

points_reshape = irregular_points.reshape(3, 5, 2)
x, y = np.transpose(points_reshape)
x_mean = x.mean(axis=0)
y_mean = y.mean(axis=1) 
regular_points = np.transpose(np.meshgrid(x_mean, y_mean))
regular_points
>>> 
array([[[ 0.99      ,  5.1       ],
        [ 0.99      ,  7.        ],
        [ 0.99      ,  9.        ],
        [ 0.99      , 11.03333333],
        [ 0.99      , 13.        ]],

       [[ 1.99      ,  5.1       ],
        [ 1.99      ,  7.        ],
        [ 1.99      ,  9.        ],
        [ 1.99      , 11.03333333],
        [ 1.99      , 13.        ]],

       [[ 3.04      ,  5.1       ],
        [ 3.04      ,  7.        ],
        [ 3.04      ,  9.        ],
        [ 3.04      , 11.03333333],
        [ 3.04      , 13.        ]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cluster algorithm like KMeans:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

irregular_points = np.array([[1.1,5.], [0.85,7.1], [0.9,9], [1.1,11], [1.,13.1],
                   [1.9,5.2], [2.,6.9], [1.95,9], [2.1,11.1], [2.,13.1],
                   [3.0,5.1], [3.1,7.0], [3.,9], [3.0,11.], [3.1,12.8]])

kmeans_x = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(irregular_points[:, 0, np.newaxis])
kmeans_y = KMeans(n_clusters=5).fit(irregular_points[:, 1, np.newaxis])

clusters_x = kmeans_x.predict(irregular_points[:, 0, np.newaxis])
clusters_y = kmeans_y.predict(irregular_points[:, 1, np.newaxis])

regular_points_x = kmeans_x.cluster_centers_[clusters_x]
regular_points_y = kmeans_y.cluster_centers_[clusters_y]

regular_points = np.asarray([[regular_points_x[i], regular_points_y[i]] for i in range(irregular_points.shape[0])])
>>>
array([[[ 0.99      ,  5.1       ],
        [ 0.99      ,  7.        ],
        [ 0.99      ,  9.        ],
        [ 0.99      , 11.03333333],
        [ 0.99      , 13.        ]],

       [[ 1.99      ,  5.1       ],
        [ 1.99      ,  7.        ],
        [ 1.99      ,  9.        ],
        [ 1.99      , 11.03333333],
        [ 1.99      , 13.        ]],

       [[ 3.04      ,  5.1       ],
        [ 3.04      ,  7.        ],
        [ 3.04      ,  9.        ],
        [ 3.04      , 11.03333333],
        [ 3.04      , 13.        ]]])
```